# Pass a Function to another user in Bash?

Tags: bash

Is there any way that I can pass a Function from one user to another user?

For example, I have a small Bash script that I execute as Root:

```
#!/bin/bash
user_func(){
  whoami
  exit
}
su vagrant -c 'user_func'
```

However, the user_func Function isn't defined for the Vagrant user, only for Root, and can't be executed.

My other option would be to have multiple lines of

```
su vagrant -c 'cmd1' 
su vagrant -c 'cmd2'
, etc
```

Or, execute multiple commands ex: `su vagrant -c 'cmd1; cmd2; cmd3;'`, but I'd prefer to not have the excess, especially when attempting to execute more than 5 commands as the Vagrant user.

Is it possible to pass a Function to another user from within the same script (ex. not creating a script on disk as a different user and then executing that generated script)? Or is there another option that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you need to `export` that function definition first:

```
#!/bin/bash
user_func (){
  whoami
  exit
}
export -f user_func
su vagrant -c 'user_func'
```

should do the trick.

The `-f` tells `export` that this is a function name rather than a variable name. Quoting from `help export`:

> Marks each NAME for automatic export to the environment of subsequently
>       executed commands.
>   ....
>
> **Options:**
>
> ```
>  -f   refer to shell functions
> ```

As pointed out by peterph and Stephane in the comments, this assumes two things:

1. That your `su` command will not overwrite the user's environment
2. That `vagrant`'s login shell is `bash`. If not, you can use the alternative `su` command line provided by Stephane:

   ```
   su vagrant -c 'bash -c user_func'
   ```

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was hoping for. I didn't realize that you would be able to export the function. This worked just as I was hoping it would after editing the sample script. Thanks!

Comment: Nice, but won't work in cases where `su` overrides the environment.

Comment: Note that it only works if the login shell of `vagrant` is `bash`. If not, `su vagrant -c 'bash -c user_func'`

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit hackish, but you can print the definition of the function inside the sommand passed to `su` and then you can of course use it.

```
$ function foo { do_some_stuff_here; }
$ su test -c "$(typeset -f foo); foo"
```

This will work even if for some reason the environment of the shell spawned by `su` will be overwritten, since it puts the definition after shell initialization. If you write the function compatibly enough, it will even work when the two users in question are using different shells.

Comment: +1 Really neat trick! Just a question though, can the `su` shell's environment be overwritten by external factors? I mean, in this case you have complete control over the `su` command line since it's in a script. How can its new shell's environment be overwritten?

Comment: For example the shell spawned by `su` might do some initialization of environment. Also `su` itself might strip some of the caller's environment to tighten security a bit (although this is usually done by more powerful alternatives like `sudo`).

Answer (score 0):

That's not a script you have, it's a function.  It sounds like you *want* a script, though.  Make a proper script and put it, as your needs require, either in `/usr/local/bin`, or in `/home/vagrant/bin`, and than you should be able to e. g. `su vagrant -c '/home/vagrant/bin/myscript.sh'`

Comment: It's a function within a sample script. My hope was to include everything that I want to do within this single script (commands run as Root, and as the Vagrant user), and not have to have a separate script for the Root user and a separate script for the Vagrant user.

Answer (score 0):

Another somewhat more portable way to do this (no bash dependency) Is to have your script call its self and have its behavior change based on either context (uid) or parameters. examples of this are given in the documentation for `super` where they show a script that needs root permissions, calling its self through super when not root.